# Kubernetes Limit Ranges Override

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Let's say I set the following Limit Ranges to namespace X:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
     memory: 1Gi
     cpu: 0.5
    defaultRequest:
     memory: 256Mi
     cpu: 0.2
    type: Container
```

These limits are sufficient for most pods in namespace X. Some pods need more resources but a pod requesting more than default.memory, default.cpu will be rejected.

My question is, is there any way (in manifest or otherwise) to override these limits such that the pod can request more than the limit set to the namespace? I know it kinds beats the purpose of Limit Ranges but I'm still wondering if there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you do not limit your memory/cpu to a minimum/maximum of memory/cpu. You only set "defaults" to every Pod which is created. With your given LimitRange, you can still override custom Limits/Requests in the Deployment of your Pod.

If you would like to set a minimum/maximum you have to add something like this to your LimitRange:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-min-max-demo-lr
spec:
  limits:
  - max:
      cpu: "800m"
    min:
      cpu: "200m"
    type: Container
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/#create-a-limitrange-and-a-pod